# Why do Proteins store energy when the body already contains Carbohydrates and Lipids?

Tags: proteins, lipids, energy, carbohydrates

We already know that lipids are a source of long term energy and carbohydrates are much faster energy releasing sources. So why do we need specific proteins within the body to store energy?
**Are proteins some sort of much quicker sources of energy?**
I really can't understand.
Thanks for answering.

Comment: Which protein energy-stores are you referring to? Could you add sources to your claim?

Comment: Well I was referring to plant seeds and eggs which have proteins which act as energy sources.

Comment: Proteins aren't used to store energy but to build structures. They can be burnt if needed though.

Comment: Any molecule (and atoms also), contains some-amount of energy (unstability, or ability to do some work), within its structure.

Comment: I think user @Mithoron should write their comment as an answer.